# liquid-fire trigger modal from action when property in controller is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, modal-dialog

I have a checkbox in my Ember app that changes the value of a property in the controller to false/true.

Also I'm using liquid-fire for modals, and in one action inside of a component I want to check if that property is false, and from there trigger the modal.
What can I use to trigger the modal from the action??
http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/#/modals

Comment: What did you decide to do?